# apply CSS for the first label of div

Tags: css, css-selectors

i would like to apply a specific css to a specific label in my html
this is my HTML

```
<div id="registration">
    <div>
        <label>Localisation</label>**//this is the target label to apply css** 
        <div id="registration_localisation">
            <div>
                <label>Gouvernorat</label>
                <select id="registration_localisation_gouvernorat">
                  <option value="1">Ariana</option>
                  <option value="2">Ben Arous</option>
                  <option value="3">Bizerte</option>
               </select>
                </div>
                 <div>
                <label for="registration_localisation_ville">Ville</label>
                <input type="text" id="registration_localisation_ville">
                 </div>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div>
        <label>Annonceur</label>**//this is the target label to apply the css** 
        <div id="registration_annonceur">
            <div>
                <label for="registration_annonceur_Nom">Nom</label>
                <input type="text" id="registration_annonceur_Nom">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="registration_annonceur_Email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="registration_annonceur_Email">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="registration_Telephone" >Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" id="registration_annonceur_Telephone">
            </div>
        </div>
         </div>

</div>
```

i used many pseudo classes but i didn't find any solution 
any idea please ?

Comment: @Pranavc, is that CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this way where you can style all your label inside the div contained into `registration`

```
#registration > div > label{
   //your css
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4kAq/)

Comment: glad to help you, remind to accept the correct answer to help other guy with your same problem @hamza437

Answer (score 4):

Just give it a class. Classes may be repeated in HTML, like;

```
<label class="class1">Localisation</label>
```

and in your css,

```
.class1{
  //styling
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**CSS3 way**

```
#registration div label:first-child {
    // specific styles for just the first label item
}
```

Or

```
#registration div label:nth-first-of-type{
// specific styles for just the first label item
}
```

**jQuery Way**

```
<script>
$( "#registration div label:first" ).css( "font-style", "italic" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
#registration > div > label:first-of-type {}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Match labels who are the first, direct child of a div.

```
div > label:first-child {}
```

Actually it would be much better if you could add some classes to your elements. Matching wide selector such as `div` is a bad idea for future maintainability. Changing your markup will break your style.